# AdaptiveCard: Action.ToggleVisibility for Action

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Is it possible to toggle the visibility of an Adaptivecard action? The following does not work:

```json
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.2",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Press the buttons to toggle the button!",
      "wrap": true
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "id": "btnShow",
      "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
      "title": "Show!",
      "targetElements": [
        {
          "elementId": "btnHide",
          "isVisible": true
        },
        {
          "elementId": "btnShow",
          "isVisible": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "btnHide",
      "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
      "title": "Hide!",
      "targetElements": [
        {
          "elementId": "btnHide",
          "isVisible": false
        },
        {
          "elementId": "btnShow",
          "isVisible": true
        }
      ],
      "isVisible": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: We also tried using the card json provided and facing the same issue. It seems like toggling the visibility of an Adaptive Card action is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actions alone cannot be hidden/shown. They need to be nested in a container within body, which supports that feature. This one is an alternative:

```json
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.2",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Press the buttons to toggle the button!",
      "wrap": true
    },

    {
      "id": "btnShow",
      "type": "ActionSet",
      "actions": [
        {
          "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
          "title": "Show!",
          "targetElements": [
            {
              "elementId": "btnHide",
              "isVisible": true
            },
            {
              "elementId": "btnShow",
              "isVisible": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },


    {
      "id": "btnHide",
      "type": "ActionSet",
      "actions": [
        {
          "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
          "title": "Hide!",
          "targetElements": [
            {
              "elementId": "btnHide",
              "isVisible": false
            },
            {
              "elementId": "btnShow",
              "isVisible": true
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "isVisible": false
    }
  ],

  "actions": []
}
```